# is there a way to create Keystone lists in runtime after keystone initialisation?

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

I'd like to create a KeystoneJs (v5.0.6) during runtime as some lists might be dynamically generated by the user.

If I run the following command after keystone has been intialised, I get the error: "Error: keystone.createList must be called before keystone.prepare()"

```
keystone.createList("MyDynamicList", {
    fields: {
      name: { type: Text },
      email: {
        type: Text,
        isUnique: true,
      },
    },
  });
```

Is there a way lists can be generated dynamically during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible, all the lists (and fields) has to be provided in `keystone.createList` method. keystone generates all the schema for GraphQL before you run `keystone.connect`.

There was a [PR and request for delaying initialization](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/842) in case someone wanted to add a field using a plugin before `keystone.connect` call which was denied.

Based on that discussion it is highly unlikely that this type of request even be priority for long.